# Why some code examples from The C Programming Language book don't work as expected?

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn C Language, and I'm reading and testing a lot about it, but sometimes is difficult to understand why somethings just don't work as expected. Why the example code showed on page 18 of The C Programming Language, Second Edition (Kernighan and Ritchie), don't work? It doesn't show any results for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf ("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: How did you use the program?

Comment: This program reads from standard input, so you need to give it something to read, like `a.out < file.txt` or else typing from the keyboard and then entering an EOF (on Unix you can enter EOF by typing `^D`).

Comment: Note that K&R is rather hopelessly outdated by today's standards, conventions and best practices. So after you're done with it, try to research&study more modern C, so you're not stuck with bad habits.

Comment: What on this program doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The C Programming Language*, Second Edition by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie is a very good book, but it is quite old and refers to an outdated definition of the C language. The program you posted uses an obsolete syntax for `main`. It should be modified as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the difference is minimal and in this particular case, the above version would also compile with the pre-ansi compilers in use at the time the book was written.

The program reads bytes from the standard input and just counts how many it could read before reaching the end of file.

You should run this program from a terminal window and type some data and signal the end of file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> on unix systems such as linux and OS/X or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> on Microsoft systems.

You can also redirect input from a file and will get the number of bytes in this file, possibly adjusted on Microsoft systems due to line ending conversion.

Running the program directly from an IDE is not demonstrative because IDE's usually do not keep the terminal window open when the program exits, preventing the user from seeing the final output.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't show anything because it's waiting for input.

If you're running this like `./the_executable`, it'll always be reading your input because of `getchar()`. And it'll show the results only after the input stream ends.

You can cut it off manually by pressing Control+D. Or use the contents of a file as input:

```
./the_executable < test_file.txt
```

Comment: As side note: On Windows one have to press Control+Z to signal `EOF`. +1

Answer (score 1):

It should indeed work as expected.

The reason why you are confusing it with not working because you are expecting `printf` to print something for you (value of `nc`), but the catch is there is another statement `getchar()` before `printf` which is reading *standard input* with the help of `while` loop until you input EOF which is entered by `^D (control + D)` in unix, like `cat` command if you used on *nix or by redirecting input to your program from a file using `<` operator, like

```
./a.out < someFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the "end of file" condition. So ctrl Z or ctrl C should work.